# Bootstrap3 Yii widget include error

Tags: php, yii, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have configured Yii bootstrap3 extension `BsHtml` and `bootstrap.widgets.BsPanel` are working fine but when I use  `bootstrap.widgets.BsGridView` or `BsNavbar` I am getting following error:

```
include(BsWidget.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory 

on F:\wamp\www\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(427)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
Yii::import('bootstrap.widgets.BsWidget');
```

before class definition, to look for it, whenever needed

Answer (score 0):

You can insert

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap.widgets.BsWidget', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap/behaviors/BsWidget');
```

in file `protected/config/main.php` before returning array.

Answer (score 0):

first you should open the main.php in protected/config/main.php
find this cod in the main.php

```
  'components'=>array(
```

and then add the below code in the  array

```
  'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
```

for example

```
'components'=>array(
       'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
    ),
```

after that you should go to the protexted/views/layouts/main.php
and find this html

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
      <!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
```

and then replac it with

```
    <?php
    echo yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
    ?>
```